# 2067 Plot Hole Explanation

Tags: plot-explanation, 2067

In [*2067* (2020)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1918734/), the main character's father tells him over the phone to go for a walk, seemingly knowing that his mother would be murdered, and that he'd meet the other side character as a result. I think his name was jude. Now, it seems as if his father was doing this because he knew the future required it...however, this specific plot thread never manifests. His father never received insider knowledge from the future, and so he had no reason to send his son for a walk, and to meet Jude, or for his mother to die.

It can also be said that he had no reason to DNA lock the time machine, because again, he had not received any reason from the future to do so. He did not yet know that he'd be betrayed and murdered. He figures that out in the next few moments.

So in short, he had no reason to put the bracelet on his son, he had no reason to send him out for his mother to die, etc. The movie seems to articulate that this is some heavy plot element...but never actually justifies or utilizes any of it. It's just sort of there. Almost as if the writers intended on Jude being some sort of pivotal element that would change the future...but he was pretty much irrelevant, because again, the main characters father knew nothing about him.

Is this a plot hole? Was it somehow explained, and i just didn't catch it?

Comment: https://www.thecinemaholic.com/2067-ending-explained/

Comment: @BCdotWEB Already read that, it does not answer my question in any capacity; they gloss over this event completely, actually.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I think you are missing a key part in the sequence here. The science team receives back the ping immediately with the message *"Send Ethan Whyte"*. This reply is the very first event in the timeline of the movie. Though if you've seen the movie, clearly it originates at the end.

The Father, at a later date that is Ethan's Birthday, is apparently suspicious of the director (sorry I don't remember names) and decides to lock in his Son somehow via the unique wrist machine and DNA tracing so that only he can activate the time machine for the return trip.

Now, your confusion is in the 3rd event of the timeline: why does he call the wife to meet them somewhere? Understandably it is confusing because the movie implies that he did this for their safety but like you said gives no explicit reason. It takes a bit of assumption here but given the interaction and decision to DNA lock his son, he must have had the suspicion that the director *would* override the science team's intent to save the current humanity and instead save a select few. The movie doesn't really explain why he sent his family out at a random time alone ultimately to be nearly killed but I guess you can assume he believed the director may try something like killing his son or kidnapping him (which she more or less does).

The only logical explanation for the killing is.. a) they really were randomly mugged, or b) the mother was killed by a hired assassin by the director before she found out about the DNA lock (though this really seems weak reasoning). I think the main plot point behind all of it is that Jude was in fact not a random savior but a hired assistant to the director of the last big corporation. They just didn't bother clearing up the *why* of the events.

Hope that clears up why it isn't a plot hole though. That said, I do think the movie offered a different plot hole. Like how do you change a past if the future you make changes the future you are in? I liked how the movie first treated time travel like something written in stone as this seems more logical if time travel were ever to be possible, but it twisted things at the end allowing for a rosy future. But I digress, nearly every time travel paradigm is flawed anyway.